# Zend controller's predispatch method

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, controller, request

I was reading [this](http://devzone.zend.com/1692/zend-framework-mvc-request-lifecycle/) to understand zend's MVC Request Lifecycle. 
But i can't think of any cases in zend where i would use a controller's predispatch method , isn't the init method enough for the code that i want executed before controller's actions .

What should exactly should be in a controller's predispatch and not init .

Can you give an example ?

Comment: Been a long, long time since I've written a Zend application (hence this being a comment and not an answer), but the first thing that comes to mind is if you had an authentication helper that was making sure the user has permission to access the controller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Zend_Controller_Action - Object Initialization](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.initialization) and the following section [Pre and Post Dispatch Hooks](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.prepostdispatch).  They both go into some detail on the two, and the Action Controller itself.

`init()` is more for setting up the controller object and doing initialization that will be available to all of your actions.  Since `init()` runs prior to `preDispatch()`, anything you set up in `init()` will be available for `preDispatch()` to use.  While it is possible to forward or redirect from `init()`, it is best practice to do it from `preDispatch()` because it runs prior to dispatching the controller action.

From the manual:

> **Note: Usage of init() vs. preDispatch()**   What is the difference between them (init and preDispatch), and what actions would you take
>   in each?
>
> The **init()** method is primarily intended for extending the
>   constructor. Typically, your constructor should simply set object
>   state, and not perform much logic. This might include initializing
>   resources used in the controller (such as models, configuration
>   objects, etc.), or  assigning values retrieved from the front
>   controller, bootstrap, or a registry.
>
> The **preDispatch()** method can also be used to set object or
>   environmental (e.g., view, action helper, etc.) state, but its primary
>   purpose is to make decisions about whether or not the requested action
>   should be dispatched. If not, you should then **_forward()** to
>   another action, or throw an exception.
>
> **Note:**  **_forward()** actually will not work correctly when executed from **init()**, which is a formalization of the intentions
>   of the two methods.

Answer (score 2):

to extend drew010's answer here is an example of how I use preDispatch() and int():

```
public function preDispatch() {

        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('admin');
    }

    /**
     *initiaize the flashmessenger and assign the _session property
     */
    public function init() {

        if ($this->_helper->FlashMessenger->hasMessages()) {
            $this->view->messages = $this->_helper->FlashMessenger->getMessages();
        }
        //set the session namespace to property for easier access
        $this->_session  = new Zend_Session_Namespace('location');

    }
```

I use preDispatch() to set the layout for every action as it not the default layout and in init() I initialize my flash messenger and setup the session namespace for this controller and initialize the session as a property.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one popular gotcha where you can waste loads of resources using init() instead of preDispatch(): if you do access control using controller plugin's preDispatch() method then call sequence will be: YourController::init(), YourAccessPlugin::preDispatch(), YourController::preDispatch(), YourController::whateverAction. This means that if you do any heavy lifting in init() then unauthorized users **can trigger it**. Say for e.g. you start a new session namespace in init() then mindless search bots can cause your session database to be littered with empty sessions. So stick to very basic simple stuff in init, avoid touching or modifying any resources, avoid database access.